# Token expiration from FIWARE Keyrock using oauth2

Tags: oauth-2.0, access-token, fiware, keystone, fiware-keyrock

In FIWARE Keyrock, using oauth2, how to I change the duration of the tokens from the default 3600 seconds?

I tried to change keystone.conf - [token] - expiration, with no success. I already get the information that oauth2 is not original from Openstack Keystone project, so that is the reason this configuration does not work.

Comment: Answered in https://ask.fiware.org/question/657/keyrock-token-duration/